# Creating protocol handler in new Firefox?

Tags: firefox, protocol-handler

I just came to know that **Forefox no longer support XPCOM component for creating extensions** ..
I want to create an extension which will **handle my protocol which will collect information from different sources via my NPRUNTIME plugin and render webpage accordingly** ..
in past I used to create protocol handler by implementing `nsIProtocolHandler`

but as there is no XPCOM support in new Firefox for extension development ..
How do I approach issue ?
Is it possible in New version of firefox?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you "came to know" that Firefox will no longer support XPCOM components in extensions.  [There have been some changes for Firefox 4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0), but it's still supported and not likely going away any time soon.